# Why does the rotation of the material on my Earth model shift in the viewport Material view? This one uses cycles and nodes

Tags: materials, 3d-view

I posted this question a few days ago; however, I couldn't get an answer. So I decided (at the urging of @Uncle Snail) to do one using cycles, but the same thing happens:
It looks fine in the Rendered view of the viewport. But I would like to see it in the Material view so I can edit it while the material is correctly displayed. Also, there is a bump map applied in addition to the material. The .blend file (with the packed files) is linked.

[image]
[image: Side-by-side of the material and rendered viewport views]

Comment: What kind of texture mapping did you use?

Comment: The Coordinates are Generated, and the Projection is Sphere. All X, Y, and Z offsets are 0. All X,Y, and Z sizes are 1.0."From Dupli" is unchecked.

Comment: In my material view-port it doesn't even show anything. However, I think your problem is that one of your textures is in a different place than another. Try that. (If I were you, I'd just learn to use Cycles as well, but I know that wasn't the question. Then I would be able to help more though.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @Uncle Snail. I have two textures applied - one of which is just a bump map. The texture being displayed in the Material view port is the same texture in the Rendered view port. Or am I missing something? Also, where do you suggest I go to learn Cycles?

Comment: To learn Cycles, I would suggest going to almost any Blender tutorial place that exists. Almost everyone is using it now, so it shouldn't be hard to find. It may be a large transition at first, but once you get used to it, it's waaaay easier and more effective. I learned mostly from BlenderGuru.com , but I would also recommend watching some tutor4U on YouTube for beginners in Blender or cycles (try the cloth material tutorial). About the material... I don't really know how the Blender Internal viewport works, but I think maybe it is displaying part of your bump map (on the bottom) which is off

Comment: I'm not sure why the rest would be off. You'll need someone who knows more than I to fully answer the question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the suggestions, @UncleSnail .  I started looking into cycles today, and I will check out the ones you mentioned.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @Uncle Snail, This one uses cycles.  Do you think you can figure out what is going on here in the Material viewport?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure why, but it's a glitch in Blender. I've never seen it before, but when you change the image mapping to sphere, it **only** changes the mapping for the render, and not the viewport. I'll run some more tests, but I believe this is a bug. I tried with a version of 2.76 as well, so it's not just 2.77. I'll run some more tests, and then get back to you in a little bit.

Comment: Okay, it is the same way on some old sphere files I have. I don't know why I never realized it before, but it seems to be a glitch.

Comment: If you like, you may search through the bugs to see if it has already been reported, and if it hasn't, report it. There may be good reasons (for performance) that they aren't doing this, and thinking about it, it makes sense, but I think it is a bug that fixing should not really slow things down. Computationally, I do see why this happens, but I would have thought it would be fixed. I also don't see why this would happen in blender internal. Cycles I see why, the way BI works, I would think you wouldn't have this error.

Comment: Thanks for all of the effort and information, @Uncle Snail. How do I search through the bugs to see if it has been reported (sorry; I'm still learning)? I'll certainly report the bug if it hasn't been reported already.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug, which is fixed in the [version 2.78](https://www.blender.org/download/).

[image]